# I'm having trouble with using the update sql command in C#.net

Tags: c#, sql

I'm having trouble using the sql update statement in C#. Every command I have executed so far works except my update command. Is there something special you have to do to your c#.net code in order to make the update sql command to work?

Here is my code where the programs stops workings.

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // <--- stops here
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("EXECUTED QUERY!"); // <--- does not get here
```

SQL SYNTAX

```
"UPDATE Users SET username = '" + txtUsername.Text + 
"', password = '" + txtPassword.Text + 
"' WHERE username = '" + txtUsername.Text + "'"
```

If more information is needed about my code just let me know.

Comment: Does it throw an exception? Can you paste a sample of what the query string looks like after it has been evaluated? Are you sure you've `.Open()`ed the connection before you execute the query?

Comment: Better read up on [SQL injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953.aspx). See also: [Exploits of a Mom](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Never build an sql statement using a string! you are asking for an sql injection attack with the user called ';drop table users'

Comment: please provide more code and an error if you're getting one.

Comment: post the exception being thrown

Answer (score 2):

Try parameterizing your query (to avoid SQL injection attacks) and then executing it within a `try-catch` to see if it's throwing an exception. EG:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString);
conn.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Users SET username = @Username, password = @Password WHERE username = @OldUsername";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Username", txtNewUsername.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Password", txtPassword.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@OldUsername", txtOldUsername.Text));

try
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.Writeline(String.Format("{0} thrown: {1}", ex.GetType().Name, ex.Message));
}
```

Also note that you're using the same username field for both the `SET` clause and the `WHERE` clause, which would fail if the user entered a different username that isn't already in the database (not to mention, you should probably check to make sure the username they're changing belongs to them and not someone else).

Comment: Thanks for the helpful tips. But going back to my code, ignore anything about sql injection at the moment. My statement looks correct and everything, correct? If it does could you explain my my query could not be executing? No error message is given off on my stack trace or anything like that.

Comment: Dennis, nothing besides the reuse of the same `txtUsername.Text` in both the SET and the WHERE looks wrong. But you really need to see if an exception is being thrown, because it may tell you exactly what you did wrong. EG: if there's a quote mark in either the username or the password, then the query will fail.

Comment: Re-write this query to use parameters.  There's no reason to ever, ever write a query like this.  Always use parameters.  Once you fix that you can figure out where the exception is coming from

Comment: Alright, I finally got it to be nice, Here is what the trace says. According to it I'm trying to insert text elements into a varchar field. Is there a way to change that? It's weird because my insert works just fine?

Comment: 'The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.'

Comment: Are you using Winforms? WPF? ASP? From what you describe, it sounds like you didn't dereference the `.Text` property correctly and are trying to insert the control rather than the control's contents. Make sure whatever `.Text` returns, it's a string rather than any other data type.

Comment: I am using an asp textbox(s).

Answer (score 0):

Following from Joe S's answer of SQL Injection, escape out your tablename and the fieldnames as these will be reserved using square brackets, e.g.

```
"UPDATE [Users] SET [username] = '" + txtUsername.Text + "', [password] = '" + txtPassword.Text + "' WHERE [username] = '" + txtUsername.Text + "'"
```

Comment: Putting the table names in square brackets will not prevent a SQL-injection attack.

Comment: Of course it won't, the most likely problem will be escaping out the object names, i.e. password and username are reserved words.  SQL injection is a given in this context, i.e. implement...